# Is there a point of repenting if we do not regret our sins?

Tags: tawba, masturbation

I am a teen and addicted to masturbation and sometimes watching "it" unfortunately. I know it's a sin but I just can't stop or feel guilty. Would Allah still forgive me if I ask?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are seeking advice here in itself, shows you feel guilty enough to seek help. The only thing that will soften your heart will be to continue with your repentance, Sadaqah, and fasting. Even if you think that you don’t feel guilty and that you are happy with your sins, continue until you are humbled. Intentions and action are both required.

I also recommend reading this question from IQA [here.](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/247976/regret-the-most-important-aspect-of-repentance)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Allah will forgive you once you repent with sincerity and work towards not repeating the sin.

I'm not sure of your exact age but assume you have achieved puberty. So if you are financially & emotionally capable, it is recommended that you get married.

Alternately, try to fast often, as it increases your taqwa and keeps you away from fitnah.

> Narrated `Abdullah:
>
> We were with the Prophet (ﷺ) while we were young and had no wealth. So
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O young people! Whoever among you can
> marry, should marry, because it helps him lower his gaze and guard his
> modesty (i.e. his private parts from committing illegal sexual
> intercourse etc.), and whoever is not able to marry, should fast, as
> fasting diminishes his sexual power."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 5066](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5066)

Answer (score -1):

Allah says many times in Quran, and the prophet Mohammed PBUH also, that if you repent from a sin sincerely and regret doing it, Allah would accept it, as long as your soul is still in your body. But that doesn't mean you could still masturbate, you must do whatever you can to stop it, your life depends on that.

Comment: But what can I do to stop it? also what if I don't regret doing it?

Comment: Just stop doing it, that's not so difficult.

Answer (score -1):

There is difference of opinion among scholars whether masturbations' is sin or not. There are scholars who said هو ماؤك فأهرقه ( it is your water, so pour it out). I don't remember the reference.

For most of boys, if they don't masturbate, they will end up having nocturnal emission. it is similar to masturbation in dream. I don't think something will be halal when done in dream and haram when done otherwise.

Allah knows best.